# Position on which an object receives less light

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

The light an object receives is proportional to the  intensity of the source and inversely proportionally to the distance squared, let's say we place two sources 10 feer apart from each other one source emits 3 times more than the other, at what position should we place an object to receive less light

$$L = \frac{3}{d^2}+\frac{1}{d^2}$$
$$L' = \frac{-6}{d^3} + \frac{-2}{d^3}$$
$$0 = \frac{-8}{d^3}$$
$$d = (-8)^{\frac{1}{3}} = -2
$$
$$L'' >0 (local minum)$$
I know this is wrong because I am not using the 10 feet data...

Comment: "I before E except after C".

Comment: Is it necessary that the object is always at equal distance from both the light sources? If not, why have you used the same $d$ for both light sources?

Comment: @Grimm yea I am wrong  in that aspect

Comment: If we assume distance from one light source to be $d$, then try to think what would be its distance from the other light source incorporating the data provided in the question.

Comment: 10-d.........???????

Comment: Yeah so, use that in the equation you made and do the same calculations you did and see if you get the answer.